# How to run anchor tests partially?

Tags: anchor, testing, anchor-test

Having a project that has grown a bit larger I have modularized the tests into separate files. Calling the test script works fine with running over all files. But I couldn't figure out or find anything on how to run tests partially.

Using this project as an example:
https://github.com/tobealive/anchor-solana-twitter/

**Being able to run a single - on the fly specified - test file is the nice-to-have I'm looking for here.** Or running parts of a test when using a single file containing all unit tests.

A predigested solution would be top-notch. Also, every tip about resources one should look into to achieve this would be of great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely have something like this in your `Anchor.toml` file:

```
[scripts]  
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"
```

Change the wildcard `(*)` character to specify exactly what test file you want to run.

For example if you have multiple test files `test1.ts`, `test2.ts`, and `test3.ts` all located in your `test` folder that you want to run selectively at different times, then you would need to edit your `Anchor.toml` file to:

```
[scripts]  
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/**.ts"  
test1 = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/test1.ts"  
test2 = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/test2.ts"  
test3 = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/test3.ts"
```

This way you can use `anchor run test` to run all tests at once, `anchor run test1` to run the `test1.ts` file, `anchor run test2` to run the `test2.ts` file, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this would require always changing the Anchor.toml file to be able to test a single unit and also if one wants to run all tests again. I think handling it statically like this is too much of a bummer to be a real solution to the problem. But it certainly could be automated in a script that does a change temporary for a test run and then restores the wildcard.

Comment: You would just need to hardcode different scripts and run them selectively. I'll update the answer to show how

Comment: This solution no longer works in Anchor 0.29.0 See my post https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8088/how-to-run-only-one-test-in-anchor-0-29-0

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Anchor.toml,
exmaple:

```
[scripts]
create = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/Blockchain/Create.ts"
```

Comment: This comes close to a solution. It won't allow running it like `anchor test`, but when having an `anchor localnet` running, one would be able to quickly run single test files with e.g., `anchor run create`  or other scripts added to the section

Comment: you got it. that's how it is