# How to run ONLY ONE test in Anchor 0.29.0?

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

This error came back in 2023 after the previous post here from 2022 August.

`anchor run test1` now gave me `Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: fetch failed` !!??
That is because it does not run a local network then deploy my programs... So that is new in Anchor 0.29.0

My Anchor.toml

```
[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"

test1 = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/zero-copy.ts"
```

`anchor test -h` gave me `--run <RUN>  Run the test suites under the specified path`

When I ran `anchor test --run ./tests/zero-copy.ts`, Anchor still ran all tests!!??

Workaround: change the Anchor.toml test path:

`test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/zero-copy.ts"`

But this is a workaround, not the best solution...

How can I add multiple tests in `[script]` then run one of the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> anchor run test1 now gave me Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: fetch failed !!?? That is because it does not run a local network then deploy my programs... So that is new in Anchor 0.29.0

The command `anchor test` does three things:

1. Builds the program.
2. Deploys the program, spinning the localnet validator if needed.
3. Runs the `test` script.

Running `anchor run <script>` only does step 3 and so requires you to have run the `anchor build` and `anchor deploy` commands beforehand. If you're testing on localnet it also requires that you spin up a test validator between the build and deploy steps and keep it active while you run your script.

The solution to this is running `anchor localnet` to perform the build, start-validator, and deploy steps before you run your script.